# How many people were in the original Rogue One squad?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

In *Rogue One: A Star Wars Story*, a small group of rebels go rogue to steal the Death Star plans on Scarif. Despite being vastly outnumbered and outgunned, through hope and eventually more forces join him they obtain the plans. I simply want to know: how many people were apart of the original "Rogue One" squad? Obviously Jyn, Cassian, Chirrut, Baze, K-2S0, and Bodhi are members, but is there an official number of people who were part of the group before the rebel fleet arrived?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the [squadron members](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rogue_One_(squad)) receive a name (and a small bio) in the *[Rogue One Visual Dictionary](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Rogue_One:_The_Ultimate_Visual_Guide)*

- Jyne Erso
- Cassion Andor
- Ruescott Melshi
- Taidu Sefla
- Arro Basteren
- Yosh Calfor
- Eskro Casrich
- Chirrut Îmwe
- K-2SO
- Farsin Kappehl
- Baze Malbus
- Jav Mefran
- Pao
- Bodhi Rook
- Serchill Rostok
- Stordan Tonc

Comment: I hate to be that guy, but this might be missing a few. I don't know the name of every single character in the movie, but I know that Ruescott Melshi should be there at the very least.

Comment: @DonatelloSwansino - That's my bad. I assumed wookieepedia would have the same list as the Visual Dictionary.